# Which Kafka API to study to use in order to convert a traditional Integration system into Apache Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am aware of the extreme basics of Apache Kafka. However, I have no knowledge on Kafka API's.

Suppose I have an application that takes data from a source system (through SQL queries) , processes it (through Java Code) and then inserts / updates the processed data into a target system (through SQL queries).

This is a scheduled job which runs every few hours & only picks data which is updated in the source system after the last successful run. For ex:- The last successful run is at 6 PM and the next run is scheduled at 11 PM, so only the data which is updated between 6 PM and 11 PM would be fetched from the source system.

What would be be the suggested Kafka API to study and use if I want to implement a system such as this using Apache Kafka & Java / Spring.

Also, any tutorial or Java / Spring sample code links on the suggested API would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

which database we are talking about here. There are 100 of ways to achieve this in the KAFKA world, but best implementation would the Database Sink/Source Connector. It is just a plug-in and all we need to do a minimal configuration and also you do Data Transformation and Enrichment.

For your basic understanding, kindly refer

https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-connectors-without-kafka
https://dzone.com/articles/data-ingestion-from-rdbms-by-leveraging-confluents